Why choose a wirewound resistor instead of a metal film one as the input bias resistor of an ultra low noise preamplifier?
I am reading Jim Williams' "Quantifying Silence" (Analog Devices/Linear Technology Application Note 124): in this note he describes an ultra-low noise preamplifier designed to measure the noise level of low noise low-dropout analog voltage regulators (and thus characterize these sources). The resistor I am referring to is the input \$1.2\text{k}\Omega\$ bias resistor placed just after the input decoupling low leakage capacitor as shown (inside the red circle) in the picture below (page 3 of the above reference)

I don't understand why a wirewound resistor should be used and not a metal film one: indeed

both kind of resistor types are standard choices where low noise and low thermoelectric coefficients are of importance, but while metal film ones have a nice high frequency behavior, the wirewound ones have the typical inductive behavior described in possibly every textbook, which indeed prevents its use in RF circuits.
Moreover, to rule out the possibility that the Ultronix 105A family of resistors used by Williams was preferred by him for a unique property, I found and read their datasheet without, however, noticing something outstanding.


It's possible that this author has done some careful analysis and/ or experiment in order to make this recommendation. Or, I suppose, it's possible that "we've always done it this way." My wild speculation- a thin film resistor has lots of surface relative to volume, maybe there are some odd surface effects.

Are you taking into consideration the shielding surrounding the resistor?  It is easier to shield a wirewound resistor than a metal film one.  Further, it, and its associated low noise 1.2k resistor, are fully shielded against pick-up.

As @Fred said, Jim Williams used to spend many hours in the lab testing things.  It's likely that even though there's nothing in the datasheet, he tried various resistors and found a reason to recommend the wirewound.  Unfortunate that he didn't explain it, but I'm pretty confident the reason exists.

@StainlessSteelRat I've also considered this possibility. Since wirewound resistors are intrinsically inductive, care should be taken to place them far away from magnetic pick, thus again this seems not the best choice for such an application. Moreover as you can see from the application note, p. 8, appendix A, Williams shielded two times this part of the circuit, by putting it inside the butter cookie box (!) and inside a orange juice can (!!), and this possibly avoids all external interferences. But I may be missing something here.

@Fred I think so. Possibly I should try this circuit and test various resistor choices.

@JohnD thanks. As stated in my reply to Fred, perhaps the best way to find out is to go and try.

@John D - Agreed about Jim Williams.  If he suggested something it usually had a good scientific or engineering basis.  Maybe Fred is not familiar with Jim Williams (who passed away a number of years ago).

The absence of excess noise (1/f noise) is often cited as the principal advantage of wirewound resistors over other types, see refs below:
Strategies for minimizing resistor-generated noise:

Metal film resistors


... Metal film resistors are manufactured through the evaporation or sputtering of a layer of nickel chromium onto a ceramic substrate. ... the occlusions, surface imperfections, and non-uniform depositions are more significant to the production of noise when the nickel chromium layer is thin.


Wirewound resistors


Wirewound resistors are made of alloys similar to that used in foil resistors ... the only noise insertion caused by these devices comes from the tabs used to connect the fine wire to the coarse external leads.

Resistor Types - Does It Matter?

... Wirewound resistors are the quietest, having only thermal noise, followed by metal film, metal oxide, carbon film, and lastly, carbon composition.

etc.
Excess noise only observed when a resistor is biased by external voltage or current, which is the case for the input \$1.2\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor. Unlike thermal noise, the power spectrum density of excess noise is the function of frequency. The next article introduces the parameter (\$\textit{NI}\$) to quantify excess noise in resistors:
Measurement of Excess Noise in Thin Film and Metal Foil Resistor Networks

Excess noise is commonly quantified using the Noise Index (\$\textit{NI}\$)
$$
\textit{NI} = 10 \log {{V_{rms}[\mu V]} \over {V_{DC}[V]}} \quad[\textit{dB}/\textit{decade}]
$$

With this intro, the article
Review on Excess Noise Measurements of Resistors by Daniela Walter, André Bülau, André Zimmermann
is a comprehensive report on measurement and analysis as those suggested by @DanieleTampieri in comments (perhaps the best way to find out is to go and try).
The only wirewound resistor chosen by the authors for measurements is Neohm UPW25 1K, and report figures for three types of measurement arrangements are

Setup 1 on single resistors: NI for UPW25 1K <-60 dB
Setup 2: A wirewound resistor type UPW50 was measured and excess noise was found.
Setup 2, UPW25 10K:  A wirewound resistor type UPW50 was measured and here the excess noise is on par with TDP16031002 and LT5400-1.

The figures, as we see, widely vary and no unambiguous conclusion on the use of wirewound resistors can be drawn. The article concludes that

In general, there are only a few (\$\textit{NI}\$) values in the literature given at all. This makes it hard to estimate how big the sample-to-sample variation is as well as by how much the setup or maybe other unknown parameters affect the results. The effect of sample variations for resistors in general and the reproducibility of noise measurements on the same component could be investigated.

So, the measurements suggested by OP, when performed and published,  can be a valuable contribution.

Excellent and comprehensive answer: I appreciated very much the references you gave.
